# Change address of linked Excel chart in Word

Tags: excel, charts, hyperlink, ms-word

I have an excel workbook with a large number of charts.  Each of the charts in this workbook has been linked to a word document.  I also have another workbook, which is identical to the first (has all the same graphs, sheets, etc.) except it has a different name and file location.  What I would like to do is change the linked address of the charts in the word document to this other workbook.

To achieve this, I have tried the only two possible solutions that have occurred to me:

1) In Word, went to File > Edit Links to Files and changed the address from the old workbook to the new workbook.  This method does not appear to work because i) there doesn't seem to be a way to determine which chart's address you are changing, and ii) after making the change the charts don't update with any data from the newly specified workbook.  I take this to mean that it might be linked to the new workbook but has not automatically linked to the corresponding chart.  This means that I would still need to re-specify the data for the linked charts which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

2) I have opened both the word document and the excel workbook to which the charts are currently linked and have 'Saved As' the workbook to the new workbook name and address. This has not worked because the links in the word document remained as the old workbook and did not update to the new workbook name and address.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can achieve the desired goal, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, using the "File" > "Edit Links to Files" option and manually changing the address from the old workbook to the new workbook does indeed do the trick.  It is unclear why it didn't appear to work the first time, but I have verified that it does now.